# caching in asp.net and ado.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, ado.net, .net-4.0

I have a taxes table in the database which changes maybe once a year.  our asp.net application has calculations that query the database for taxes based on the customer's province/state a lot.  I would like to avoid those round trips.  Is there a way I can use caching with Entity Framework 4?  So I want the entity based on the taxes table in my edmx, but when I perform LINQ queries against it, I don't want it to go to the database unless the cache has expired.  How would I accomplish this?

I haven't worked with asp.net data caching before, so some details on the concept would be highly appreciated.  I have read the msdn documentation on application data caching, but I'm just wondering how to make this work with EF4 in an elegant manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file base caching for that. Like you have to create a trigger on the table which will modify files on a specific location and then you can add cachedependancy on file from asp.net code. So until and unless any changes occurred in table you have to fetch data from the cache if file changes then it will validate cache and data will be fetch from the database.

Or

You can SQL Cache dependancy feature if you are using SQLServe as your backend.

Here are the some links that might help you.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031229.htm

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vishnuprasad2005/implementingcachinginasp.net11302005072210am/implementingcachinginasp.net.aspx

here are some support for caching in entityframework

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/07/09/transparent-caching-support-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

http://www.andrewdothay.net/blog/2009/01/28/LINQAndTheSqlCacheDependency.aspx

Comment: do you know if entity framework 4.0 supports any sort of caching out of the box?  the last 2 links seem dated.

Comment: No I don't think so. If you want to use out of box you can use telerik open access orm but its a paid license.

Comment: I think file base caching will work in almost all the scenarios.

Comment: I'm not EF expert, but I believe EF does in-memory caching by default based on SQL profiling -- once an entity is read from db, it does not seem to get re-read again. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2d880f3f-afce-492b-9da1-8572780b7623/